# App crashes with error AppName[5811] was suspended with locked system files:AddressBook.sqlitedb"

Tags: iphone, sqlite, background, addressbook, tel

I am using AddressBook in my app. I am fetching the address book data in the background thread. If I open my app from background my app crashes with following error:

```
    Application Specific Information:
[2786] was suspended with locked system files: 
/private/var/mobile/Library/AddressBook/AddressBook.sqlitedb
```

After my app launches from background , I am fetching address book data in background thread when my app receive UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification. Here is my code

```
    // In my ViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(appLaunchedFromBackground:)
                                          name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
    // Some more code
}

-(void)appLaunchedFromBackground:(NSNotification *) notification  {

    NSLog(@"In appLaunchedFromBackground");
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getUpdatedAddressBookData) withObject:nil];
}

-(void)getUpdatedAddressBookData {

    NSLog(@"In %s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    AddressBook *addBook = [[AddressBook alloc]init];
    [addBook fetchAddressBookDataInBackground];
    [addBook release];
    [pool drain];
}
```

Also I have CALL functionality in my app. If I CALL to seelcted no from my app & after end of CALL I again launch my app for 2 times my app crashes. For CALL I used following code:

```
 +(void)makeCallToSelectedContact:(NSString*)phoneNo{

    NSMutableString *phoneNumber = [NSMutableString stringWithString:phoneNo];

    [phoneNumber replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " 
                                 withString:@"" 
                                    options:NSLiteralSearch 
                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [phoneNumber length])];
    [phoneNumber replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"(" 
                                 withString:@"" 
                                    options:NSLiteralSearch 
                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [phoneNumber length])];
    [phoneNumber replaceOccurrencesOfString:@")" 
                                 withString:@"" 
                                    options:NSLiteralSearch 
                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [phoneNumber length])];

    NSLog(@"phoneNumber => %@",phoneNumber);
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phoneNumber]]]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phoneNumber]]];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to open");
        [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Alert" andMessage:@"This Device Doesn't Support Call Functionality"]; 
    }
}
```

How can I solve crashing problem ? Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: No. I didn't find anything for this

Answer (score 0):

By now, I found out this seems to be a safeguard new to iOS 6.

It seems that springboard will kill your app when you continue to access Addressbook after being sent into background. This may happen when you are continuing to run in the background for uploading some files or so.

It might also be that this issue is gone in 6.1. There's a similar issue with Japanese and Chinese keyboards, which access a global database with autocompletions. This issue got definitely fixed in 6.1, do chances are good your issue is gone as well.